# Installing Eclipse doesn't seem to have worked

Tags: java, eclipse, installation

I've installed Eclipse and tried to do the "Hello World" program a couple of times and for some reason it never seems to work, could anyone help me out with this because I'm quite lost seeing as I've never used Eclipse before, heres a screenshot of my UI and what I get as an error: [image]

Also I may have forgotten something very basic knowing me, seeing as it's been months since I last programmed, feel free to mention it nonetheless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to run a program full of compiler errors, so no wonder it doesn't work. In your case it's the JRE configuration—you need to bind your installed JRE to the Eclipse's JRE setup. You can type Ctrl-3, jre, enter and you'll be able to go directly to the proper preference page.

Comment: Perfect answer, I was telling Eclipse to use JRE 1.7 whereas it only detected JRE 1.6 thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is not able to find HelloWorld.class file. Might be due to compile time problems.
You can check in the output directory of your project, weather .class file is there or not.